# Dockerfile for Apache2

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache2.4

My docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 && \
    service start apache2 && \
    service enable apache2
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I have already pulled ubuntu.
But I'm getting errors such as '**unknown instruction apt-get**' and '**could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name**'.

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the backslashes are the absolute last thing on their lines; there's not a space or DOS-format carriage return after them?  Also note that, broadly speaking, `service` just doesn't work in Docker, and that a Docker image never persists a running process; you need to set `CMD` to start Apache in the foreground.

Comment: Maybe the PATH variable is not set the way you expect while building the docker image. Provide the full path to apt-get.